# How to get Credentials from EWS Auto discover / GetUserAvailability request

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

How to get Credentials from autodiscover and GetUserAvailabilityRequest for the address space configured in exchange server. "Authorization" header and "AuthType" is returning null values for the request.

Comment: You need to add the code your using to your question

Comment: @GlenScales found out the issue, mentioned it in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. I missed out setting "www-authenticate" header in the response to the unauthenticated request. Once that is set, I am able to receive the credentials for subsequent requests from exchange server.